# Square root branch selection of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

The complex function
$$
f(z) = \sqrt{(z-(a+b)) (z-(b-a))(z-(a-b)) (z+(a+b))}, \quad a,b\in \mathbb{R}, \quad a,b >0, \quad a > b
$$
has 2 branch cuts located between $z \in [-a - b,b - a ]$ and $ z \in [ a-b, a + b]$. For the choice $z = c + i\varepsilon$, and $\varepsilon \to 0^{+}$ and e.g. $a = 1.2,b = 0.8$, the real and imaginary parts in Mathematica look as

[image]

How one would rotate the branch cut so the imaginary part does not suffer from the jump?

Comment: If $\sqrt z$ is the principal value of the square root, then $\prod \sqrt {z - z_k}$ with real $z_k$ is continuous in the upper half-plane and continuous from above (that is, in direction $-i$) on the real axis.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I do not understand what you mean. My complex analysis skills are not that good.